# By RFC 1928, what should SOCKS5 client do when receive UDP reply message which ATYP is 0x03 (domain)?

Tags: socks, rfc

According to [RFC 1928](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928.html), we know the UDP request and reply header as follow:

```
 +----+------+------+----------+----------+----------+
 |RSV | FRAG | ATYP | DST.ADDR | DST.PORT |   DATA   |
 +----+------+------+----------+----------+----------+
 | 2  |  1   |  1   | Variable |    2     | Variable |
 +----+------+------+----------+----------+----------+

 ATYP address type of following addresses:
   o  IP V4 address: X'01'
   o  DOMAINNAME: X'03'
   o  IP V6 address: X'04'
```

In reply scenario, when the `ATYP` is 0x03 (domain), how can the client know the real IP address of the remote destination?

Answer (score 0):

When **receiving** a datagram from a remote host, the `ATYP` should not be `X'03'`. It should always be either `X'01'` or `X'04'` to carry the IP address of the reply sender. But, if for some reason, the UDP relay decides to set `ATYP` to `X'03'`, it means the IP is being hidden, so there is no way for the receiving client to know what the sender's IP is.

When **sending** a datagram to a remote host, the `ATYP` may be `X'03'`, if the sender wishes the UDP relay to use its own DNS resolution to determine the remote IP to send to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the lack of clarity in the RFC is really confusing.